# React - pass id from state on client to axios.get on express server

Tags: reactjs, api, express, routes, axios

I am trying to pass the id from my React app to axios.get on the server side (Express) so I get this:

```
    //get
app.get('/api/siteDashboard', (req, res, next) => {
    axios.get('https://****/api/site?id=3d5a6a8a-60d4-4488-1401-08d74bf02cbf')
    .then(response => res.json(response.data))
        .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

On the client side I have a datatable and each row has a link to a new page.  The data for the datatable is coming from the api.  I want to be able to click the link for a specific row and grab its ID from the api and open the new page based on this ID.

```
    <Link to="/Sites/SiteDashboard">
        <MDBIcon icon="fa fa-external-link-alt" size="lg" className='green-text cursor-pointer' />
    </Link>
```

I am fetching the route from the server like this in my client side React app..

componentDidMount() {

```
this.setState({ loading: true });

//const { match: { params }} =this.props

//fetch(`/api/site/?id=${this.state.siteDashboard}`)
fetch(`/api/siteDashboard`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            siteData: data,
            loading: false,
        })
    })
```

So basically, rather than hard coding the id into the axios.get request, I need to dynamically grab this from the link on the client side.  Im not sure if I am approaching this the right way so any advice appreciated.  Thanks.

React code...

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import DataTable, { memoize } from 'react-data-table-component'
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import Spinner from '../../Spinner'
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MDBContainer, MDBCard, MDBCardBody, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBIcon } from 'mdbreact';

//import SiteDashboard from './SiteDashboard';
import SiteAdd from './SiteAdd'
import SiteDashboard from './SiteDashboard'

const TextField = styled.input`
  height: 32px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 16px;

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;


const Filter = ({ onFilter }) => (
    <TextField id="search" type="search" role="search" placeholder="Search Title" onChange={e => onFilter(e.target.value)} />
);

const columns = memoize(clickHandler => [
    {
        name: 'Online',
        selector: 'cloudAccessEnabled',
        sortable: true,
        minWidth: '10px',
        center: true,
        cell: row => (
            <MDBIcon icon="circle"
                className={row.cloudAccessEnabled === true ? 'green-text' : 'red-text'} />
        )
    },
    {
        name: 'Site Ref.',
        selector: 'siteRef',
        sortable: true,
        wrap: true,
        minWidth: '40px',
    },
    {
        name: 'Name',
        selector: 'name',
        sortable: true,
        wrap: true,
        minWidth: '80px',
    },
    {
        name: 'Address Type',
        sortable: true,
        wrap: true,
        minWidth: '100px',
        //dont show this column
        hide: 6000,
        cell: row => (
            <div>
                {row.addresses && row.addresses.map(
                    ({ addressType, id }) => (
                        <div key={id}>
                            <ul>
                                <li>{addressType}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    ))}
            </div>
        )
    },
    {
        name: 'Address',
        selector: 'address',
        wrap: true,
        minWidth: '100px',
        cell: row => (
            <div>
                {row.addresses && row.addresses.map(
                    ({ addressType, address1, address2, city, county, postCode, country, id }) => (
                        <div key={id}>
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>{addressType}</strong></li>
                                <li>{address1}</li>
                                <li>{address2}</li>
                                <li>{city}</li>
                                <li>{county}</li>
                                <li>{postCode}</li>
                                <li>{country}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    ))}
            </div>
        )
    },
    {
        name: 'Control Panel',
        selector: 'controlPanel',
        minWidth: '70px',
        wrap: true,
        cell: row => (
            <div>
                {(row.controlpanel == null) ?
                    <div>no CP assigned</div> : row.controlpanel}
            </div>
        )
    },
    {
        name: 'Last Maintenance',
        selector: 'lastMaintenance',
        defaultSortAsc: true,
        sortable: true,
        wrap: true,
        minWidth: '100px',
        //hide: 1030,
        cell: row => (
            <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{row.lastMaintenance}</Moment>
        )
    },
    {
        name: 'Next Maintenance',
        selector: 'nextMaintenance',
        sortable: true,
        wrap: true,
        minWidth: '100px',
        //hide: 1030,
        cell: row => (
            <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{row.nextMaintenance}</Moment>
        )
    },
    {
        name: 'Latest Result',
        selector: 'latestResult',
        sortable: true,
        minWidth: '90px',
    },
    {
        name: 'Site Dashboard',
        minWidth: '47px',
        center: true,
        cell: row => (
            <MDBIcon onClick={clickHandler} icon="fa fa-external-link-alt" size="lg" className='green-text cursor-pointer' />
        )
    },
]);

class Sites extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            sites: [],
            toggledClearRows: false
        }
    }

    // handler for link to Site Dashboard
    handleButtonClick = () => {
        console.log("clicked");
        //<Redirect to={"/Sites/SiteDashboard" + this.state.sites.id} />
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        this.setState({ loading: true });

        //const { match: { params } } =this.props

        fetch('/api/site')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(site => {
                this.setState({
                    sites: site.array,
                    //cahnge to true to debug
                    loading: false
                });
                console.log(this.state.sites)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(error.responderEnd);
                }
            });
    }

    render() {

        // The row data is composed into your custom expandable component via the data prop
        const ExpandedSection = ({ data }) =>
            <MDBContainer fluid>
                <p className="small mt-2">
                    <strong>Notes: </strong>
                    {data.notes}
                </p>
            </MDBContainer>

        //Spinner
        const CustomLoader = () => (<div><Spinner /></div>);
        const { loading } = this.state;

        return (

            <div>
                <MDBCard className="full-width sites-dt">
                    <MDBCardBody>
                        <MDBRow className="my-4 ml-1">
                            <MDBCol sm="12" md="4" className="text-center text-md-left">
                                <h3>Sites</h3>
                            </MDBCol>
                            <MDBCol sm="12" md="8" className="text-center text-md-right">
                                <Route path="/Sites/SiteAdd" component={SiteAdd} />
                                <Link to={`/Sites/SiteAdd`}>
                                    <MDBBtn outline color="primary">
                                        <MDBIcon icon="plus" /> Add a new Site
                            </MDBBtn>
                                </Link>
                            </MDBCol>
                        </MDBRow>
                        <Link to={`/Sites/SiteDashboard`}>temp link to Site Dashboard <MDBIcon icon="fa fa-external-link-alt" size="lg" className='green-text' />
                        </Link>
                        <MDBRow>
                            <MDBCol>
                                <DataTable className="responsive-table site-headers pagination-align-left"
                                    columns={columns(this.handleButtonClick)}
                                    data={this.state.sites}
                                    defaultSortField="siteRef"
                                    defaultSortAsc={false}
                                    subHeader
                                    //subHeaderComponent={<Filter onFilter={value => setFilterText(value)} />}
                                    compact
                                    pagination
                                    highlightOnHover
                                    expandableRows
                                    expandableRowsComponent={<ExpandedSection />}
                                    progressPending={loading}
                                    progressComponent={<CustomLoader />}
                                />
                            </MDBCol>
                        </MDBRow>
                    </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCard>

            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Sites
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can a write a separate function for the API call from where you are getting ids/routes:

```
 ComponentDidMount(){
      app.get('/api/siteDashboard', (req, res, next) => {
            // your call

        })
    }
```

Here you have to make a change in route as well to add another route on the client-side, so to make URL for every item in the table.

```
<Route path='/site/siteDashboard/:id' component={youComponent} />
      //youComponent which shows the details of the item
```

and where you are mapping your items in the table, just wrap each item with

```
<Link to=`/sites/siteDashboard/${this.state.id} />
```

Now when on the component where you are showing item details :

```
var id = props.match.params.id; // this will get your id from URL
or 
var id = this.props.match.params.id;
axios.get('https://pathc/id?=${id}') //like this
```

and pass it to the API call to get its data.

Comment: ok thanks @Udit . so would the function be run on the client side or server? Im currently fetching from the client like this  fetch(`/api/siteDashboard/`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    siteData: data,
                    loading: false,
                })
            })

Comment: would this `id` be used to make another fetch API call? if so, you have to run it in the client-side code.

Comment: from what I understood you are fetching data in the first call which you using to make a table with links to the specific item which will take you to the new page on click. on second call you need an id and you'll pass it to the fetch API call to get the data for this id. Is it correct?

Comment: on the client side the fetch just gets the route from the server. all state is set on the client side so how would i run FetchAPI(state.id) on the server?

Comment: there is a link in each datatable row with an onclick handler. The id for this row is actually what needs to be returned to the api call and then open the new page using that api call. hope this makes sense.

Comment: OK @Udit  ive sort of got this working. I am now clicking through to the component and getting the row id like this http://localhost:3000/Sites/SiteDashboard?id=34a52aca-f693-4285-066e-08d74bdd1a8b How can i now get this query and pass it to my api call to request the data just for that ID? Thanks.

Comment: inside the component if you are using class based components 
you can get id inside this.props.match.params.id
if you are using functional components you will get the id value inside props.match.params.id

Comment: sorry i cant seem to get my head round this. do you mind having a look at the code in my jsfiddle. thanks very much ;) https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleste74/zxnk31eq/2/

Comment: just had to updated my main Route to <Route exact path="/Sites/SiteDashboard/:id" component={SiteDashboard} /> and change setState to this.setState({
                    siteData: data, on client and all working now.  Thanks a lot thats a big help going forward with this project ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the React code also? Will edit my answer with appropriate code

What you need to do is:

- Fetch all table data from the server side
- Create a React component for the table which will hold multiple table entries (another React component), each one with a id prop
- onClick handler for each button of each table entry
- onClick will he handled by the table item component which has the `id` prop, sending an axios request to fetch the data
- change the state once axios has returned the item's data

Comment: I have added my complete React code and a screenshot at the bottom. I was originally trying to do this with an onclick event which you can see in the handleButtonClick function.  All api get request are done on the server though so not sure how to pass the id from state to the api call. Thanks.